# Use Python CSV module to write to csv keeping the columns in the same order each time

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

Below is code that takes a list of dictionaries and writes them to a CSV file.

```
import csv

def createBaselineCSV(baselineDictionaryList, name):

    toCSV = baselineDictionaryList

    keys = toCSV[0].keys()
    print(keys)
    with open(name, 'w') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(toCSV)

contacts = [{'Name':'John Smith', 'Email':'example@email.com', 'Phone':'888-888-8888'}, {'Name':'Keith Stone', 'Email':'keith@coors.com', 'Phone':'000-000-000'}]

createBaselineCSV(contacts, 'contacts.csv')
```

However the columns of the created CSV file do not maintain a consistent format each time a new spreadsheet is created. So one time it might create a CSV that looks like:

```
Name, Email, Phone
John Smith, example@email.com, 888-888-8888
Keith Stone, keith@coors.com, 000-000-0000
```

And the next time it might make a CSV that looks like this:

```
Email, Phone, Name
example@email.com, 888-888-8888, John Smith
keith@coors.com, 000-000-0000, Keith Stone
```

Is there a good way to make sure that the CSV is created with the column cells in a fixed position each time? For example Column A  is always 'Name', Column B is always 'Email', and Column C is always 'Phone'.

I am guessing that accomplishing this will mean calling createBaselineCSV on a different data type other than a list of dictionaries(because dictionaries don't maintain a specified order), rather than reformatting the code within the function. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Don't use the DictWriter, or use collections.OrderedDict if you must. Dictionaries are not intrinsically ordered: that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is `fieldnames=keys` where `keys` comes from a dict which has no order. Just set `fieldnames=['Name', 'Email', 'Phone']` or whatever you want it to be. You can continue using dicts and `DictWriter`.

Comment: or use an OrderedDict

Answer (score 1):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) makes this very easy:

```
import pandas as pd

contacts = [{'Name':'John Smith', 'Email':'example@email.com', 'Phone':'888-888-8888'}, {'Name':'Keith Stone', 'Email':'keith@coors.com', 'Phone':'000-000-000'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(contacts)
df[['Name', 'Email', 'Phone']].to_csv('contacts.csv', index=False)
```